# How can I access data in another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm sorry if my question is too ridiculous, because I'm new to programming.

I created a project with React, I have 3 different components: navbar, sidebar and data.

I received json data from an api using hooks in my data component.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const Data = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json));
  }, []);
};
```

Now, how can I access the "data" state in the data component from other components?

I don't want to use Context api, because I've heard that it is only used in cases where the state affects all components, like authentication

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: "Lift" the data fetching into a parent component.

Comment: send it via `props` I think the simple and basic concept

Comment: The pattern you'll want to follow is called Data Down, Action Up. This article explains the concept pretty well with examples you can use: 
https://medium.com/swlh/understanding-information-flow-in-react-data-down-action-up-b6c792a8b010

Comment: You can fetch the data in a common parent component, then pass it as props to the child  components.

Answer (score 1):

I have added few lines in your codesandbox. I think this is same that you want to achieve

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-bardeen-rtogwp?file=/src/data.jsx)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who helped me. Actually, I realized that the title is not correct. What I wanted to do was to use the data brought outside the component inside the component. I did this by creating custom hooks. If anyone is curious, I leave the code below.

```html
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function useData(id = 1) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json));
  }, []);

  return { data };
}
```

Then I import and use the useData hook I created in any component.
*(I'm not even sure it's called a hook.)*
Example: `const {data} = useData(4)`

Comment: If you still need any help. we connect over the call

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use the module.exports function in the data component and then just call it in the necessary components. For example:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const Data = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json));
  }, []);
};

module.exports = data;
```

Then in the navbar component for example you call it and use it where it is necessary:

```
const Navbar = () => {
const data = require(../Data)
...
...
...
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it was a pleasure to help you.

Comment: You can't use `require` in browser environment

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: [`require`](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/) is nodejs global function

Comment: `../Data` this will throw [UnexpectedToken](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unexpected_token) error. You can't export variable declared inside function.